# Convert Large Xml file to JSON via URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my home task, I was asked to develop Restful api on server Node.js.
My problem is to convert huge XML into JSON format by using URL.

I tried to use different directories like xml-stream, xml2json.
And I found on the net a function that would do it for me, but the result was strange.
I used the following guide: https://antrikshy.com/blog/fetch-xml-url-convert-to-json-nodejs

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Parse XML to JSON.
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var https = require('https');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  function xmlToJson(url, callback) {
    var req = https.get(url, function(res) {
      var xml = '';

      res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        xml += chunk;
      });

      res.on('error', function(e) {
        callback(e, null);
      }); 

      res.on('timeout', function(e) {
        callback(e, null);
      }); 

      res.on('end', function() {
        parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
          callback(null, result);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  var url = "https://www.boi.org.il/he/BankingSupervision/BanksAndBranchLocations/Lists/BoiBankBranchesDocs/snifim_dnld_he.xml";
xmlToJson(url, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.err(err);
  }
  res.json(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});

});

module.exports = router;
```

I expected a valid JSON output and got the wrong output.

```
"{\n  \"BRANCHES\": {\n    \"$\": {\n      \"xmlns:ns0\": \"BOI_snifim_he\"\n    },\n    \"BRANCH\": [\n      {\n        \"Bank_Code\": [\n          \"13\"\n        ],\n        \"Bank_Name\": [\n          \"13001-בנק אגוד לישראל בע\\\"מ\"\n        ],\n        \"Branch_Code\": [\n          \"142\"\n        ],\n        \"Branch_Name\": [\n          \"מבשרת\"\n        ],\n        \"Branch_Address\": [\n          \"החושן 6 9079562\"\n        ],\n        \"City\": [\n          \"מבשרת ציון\"\n        ],\n        \"Zip_Code\": [\n          \"9079562\"\n        ],\n        \"POB\": [\n          \"\"\n        ],\n        \"Telephone\": [\n          \"1-599-599-142\"\n        ],\n        \"Fax\": [\n          \"02-5706001\"\n        ],\n        \"Free_Tel\": [\n          \"\"\n        ],\n        \"Handicap_Access\": [\n          \"כן\"\n        ],\n        \"day_closed\": [\n          \"יום א\"\n        ],\n        \"Branch_Type\": [\n          \"מיוחד\"\n        ],\n        \"Date_Open\": [\n          \"02/11/2004\"\n        ],\n        \"Date_Closed\": [\n          \"26/12/2016\"\n        ],\n        \"Merge_Bank\": [\n          \"\"\n        ],\n        \"Merge_Branch\": [\n          \"\"\n        ],\n        \"X_Coordinate\": [\n          \"\"\n        ],\n        \"Y_Coordinate\": [\n          \"\"\n        ]\n      },\n      {\n        \"Bank_Code\": [\n          \"13\"\n        ],\n        \"Bank_Name\": [\n          \"13001-בנק אגוד לישראל בע\\\"מ\"\n        ],\n        \"Branch_Code\": [\n          \"123\"\n        ],\n        \"Branch_Name\": [\n          \"אגוד ישיר\"\n        ],\n        \"Branch_Address\": [\n          \"אבא הילל סלבר 13 \"\n        ],\n
```

Answer (score 2):

> I expected a valid JSON output

You got valid JSON output.

See [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json):

> **res.json([body])**
>  Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter
>   converted to a JSON string using JSON.stringify().
>
> The parameter can be any JSON type, including object, array, string,
>   Boolean, number, or null, and you can also use it to convert other
>   values to JSON.
>
> ```
> res.json(null)
> res.json({ user: 'tobi' })
> res.status(500).json({ error: 'message' })
> ```

You're using `JSON.stringify()` to convert your data to a string of JSON.

Then you are passing that string to `res.json()` and getting a JSON encoded representation of the JSON.

Remove `JSON.stringify`. Then `res.json()` will encode the data as JSON just once.